# Multiple ajax requests in jQuery with many arguments in $.when method

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can I make multiples jquery ajax requests with the `$.when` method, without knowing the number of arguments?

This is my code:

```
 var ajax_loaded = new Array();

    $('.chart input[name^="qtd"]').each(function()
    {        
        ajax_loaded.push(function(){$.ajax({
            url : www + 'chart/add',
            type : 'POST',
            data : {
               qtde: $(this).val(), 
               idProd: $(this).prev().val()
            }
        })});
    });

    $.when(ajax_loaded ).done(function(){
        alert('Done');
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - use `Function.apply` to call `$.when()` with your array of unknown length:

```
var ajax_loaded = [];

$('.chart input[name^="qtd"]').each(function()
{        
    ajax_loaded.push($.ajax({
        url : www + 'chart/add',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
           qtde: $(this).val(), 
           idProd: $(this).prev().val()
        }
    });
});

$.when.apply($, ajax_loaded ).done(function(){
    alert('Done');
});
```

NB: note that you need to push the result of `$.ajax` into the array, not a function.  Pushing a closure won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're doing it might be easier to use the [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) callbacks (success and error)